# Is PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password still necessary when PasswordAuthentication=no?

Tags: ssh, password, root

Our server cluster has remote root access enabled for rescue purposes, and we generally set `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` because LDAP users can still login using password.

Recently we added an extra server with very strict access control, and we have `PasswordAuthentication` set to no so only specific users with SSH keys can login. However, a default setting of `PermitRootLogin yes` remained for some time unnoticed. (It wasn't a real issue since we also have the password of the root user deleted so no one could log in unless directly at the KVM console.)

My question is, with `PasswordAuthentication no` set, does `PermitRootLogin yes` behave identically to `prohibit-password`?

Answer (score 25):

`prohibit-password` means authenticate with any allowed mechanism that is not password and not keyboardinteractive. See [sshd_config PermitRootLogin](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitRootLogin)

`PasswordAuthentication no` just means authenticate with any allowed mechanism that is not password, obviously. See [sshd_config PasswordAuthentication](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PasswordAuthentication)

Therefore, the answer is no.

Also, `prohibit-password` is specific to the root account, `PasswordAuthentication no` is a global setting that affects all the accounts.

Note however, if you don't use keyboardinteractive, then the answer is yes (only considering the root account)

Comment: What if i want to force Root user to login using the Password and Key both

Comment: @KashyapPatel PermitRootLogin
    Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1). The argument must be yes, prohibit-password, forced-commands-only, or no. The default is prohibit-password. In your case it should be "yes"